# mysql - selecting values from a table given column number

Tags: sql, mysql, ordinals

is it possible in mysql to select a value from a table by specifying the column number instead of the column name ?

Comment: not possible, what is your underlaying purpose?

Comment: I found a post here which may be useful: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,286477,286489#msg-286489 Not sure if this is what you're looking for or not.

Comment: @ajreal Yes, it is! See [How I did it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57001010/1848245)

Answer (score 5):

No, you can not use the ordinal value of a column in the SELECT clause.

Column order is irrelevant to a database; the ordinal value is based on the list of columns in the SELECT clause.  The ordinal value is supported *after* the SELECT clause - IE: in the `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY`.  That said, using ordinals is not a recommended approach because ordinals are brittle -- if someone changes the column order in the SELECT clause, the query can be negatively impacted.

Comment: but in regular sql you can, SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM table

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible "directly" BUT with a query linked to the ORDINAL_POSITION field of the COLUMNS table from the information_schema should do the work!

Edit: COLUMNS table contains all the fields of all tables (and their positions)

Comment: You will need a PL type language or dynamic sql (not in MySQL) that can build sql strings from queries and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

I think for that you have to execute a single query using variables recursively.
like using for loop to do that.